# Empty pandas dataframe with 300+ columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have used the following code to insert alot of empty columns from txt file to a csv file, but I am not able to assign any row or column with values.

```
data = pd.read_csv('DefaultPermList.txt',sep='\n',header=None)
data = data.set_index(0).T
data.to_csv('./data.csv', index = False)

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
```

I just want to assign the the entire row consisting of 300+ column with 0 value inside my csv file. I also would like to ask how can i assign a specific row or column with a value and how can I compare a value say a string with column name to check if it matches the column name and I can assign it a value of 1?

I also have used this but it doesn't work:

```
df.loc[len(df.index)] = 0
```

Here is the expected sample:

```
APK       Andriod.permission.abc    Andriod.permission.cde     Android.perm.xyz .. up to 300+ columns
abc.apk             0                        0                           0
cde.apk             0                        0                           0
```

So basically, the first column (APK) will only store string values while rest of the columns to be assign value 0. I want it to be saved to my csv file too once values are set.

UPDATE:
I used this to assign value to whole row and it worked.

```
df.loc[0, :] = 0
```

The new problem is:
I want all rows and columns to be 0. except the first column. The first column will only store string value.
Also I would like to know how can I assign value at specific row and column index.
Moreover, how can I set a range to check specific string name with column name, suppose range is from column 2 to 320.

Comment: Please post sample input with expected output.

Comment: It is now provided with expected output

Comment: I think you need `https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html` is the sample your input ?

Comment: It is the expected sample which i want. currently it only shows empty framework with only column names.

Comment: see if the new response worked. I think you should do `df.iloc[:,1:] = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new row as a dictionary with keys from column names and values 0.
Then append it to your dataframe:

```
new_row = dict.fromkeys(df, 0)
df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```

---

*Note:*

If you want a *string* in the first column (and zeroes in all others), replace the first key in the `new_row` dictionary to that string before appending it:

```
new_row[df.columns[0]] = "something"
```

Answer (score 3):

## update 300+ columns excluding first column

Since you have 300+ columns to update to zero, I recommend doing the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df.iloc[:,1:] = 0
```

This will update all columns except the first 1 to zero.

## update specific columns to zero

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'APK':['abc.apk','bcd.apk','cde.apk','def.apk']})
df[['abc','bcd','cde','def']] = 0
print (df)
```

Alternate, you can also give:

```
df.loc[:,['abc','bcd','cde','def']] = 0
```

This will replace only the specified columns to zero.

This will result in:

```
       APK  abc  bcd  cde  def
0  abc.apk    0    0    0    0
1  bcd.apk    0    0    0    0
2  cde.apk    0    0    0    0
3  def.apk    0    0    0    0
```

## set all values in DataFrame to 0

In pandas, you have a few options. To set all values in the dataframe to 0, just give:

```
df[::] = 0
```

or

```
df.loc[:] = 0
```

or

```
df.iloc[:] = 0
```

Similarly, you can change the value of a row using one of these options:

```
df[1:2] = 1 #to replace row 1 with value = 1

df.loc[1] = 2 #to replace row 1 with value = 2 using loc

df.iloc[1] = 3 #to replace row 1 with value = 3 using iloc
```

You can also replace values in a column in similar way:

```
df['a'] = 1 # to replace column 'a' with value = 1

df.loc[:,'a'] = 2 # to replace column 'a' with value = 2

df.iloc[:,0] = 3 # to replace first column ('a') with value = 3
```

Comment: Well it doesn't work with empty dataframe or a set which only consist of columns.

Comment: @TR9, if you have an empty dataframe, how are you assigning value to a row. Isn't it already empty. Do you want to store zero in columns 2 thru n with zero?

Comment: Well I used this: df.loc[0, :] = 0 and it worked to assign whole row value to 0. But I'm now stuck with how can I assign a value at specific column and row to 1, also I wanted to assign first column with string value and rest other columns with 0.

Comment: Ye it does solve, but I am using a txt file to import these columns. Please have a look at my updated problem I mentioned in topic.

Comment: You can also give something like this: `df.loc[:,['abc','bcd','cde','def']] = 0`. It will create the column if it does not exist and assign value of 0 to it.

Comment: @TR9 or you can give `df.iloc[:,1:] = 0` to replace all columns except first column

Answer (score 2):

In a pandas DataFrame you can use the .loc method to assign values to any cell, row or column.

To assign an entire row the value of 0, use something like this:

```
df.loc[$row$, $column$] = 0
```

Set $row$ = ':' if you want all rows, otherwise you can select rows by index or a condition to match more than 1 row.

Set $column$ = ':' if you want all columns, or you can specify the name of a column or a list of column names.

e.g. If you want to assign all the columns for the row at index 1 to a value of 0, use this command:

```
df.loc[1, :] = 0
```

Update: if you wanted to change all the values in the columns to 0 for the row where APK = abc.apk, use this:

```
df.loc[df[df['APK']=='abc.apk'].index, :] = 0
```

Comment: Ok this worked: df.loc[1, :] = 0

But it seems it wasn't saved to csv file. I want it to be saved in csv file. 

I want to change all the values to 0 except the first column which is APK, the rest of columns to be 0

Comment: After replacing the values with 0 that you want, simply use the same line of code you used to save it to a csv file.

df.to_csv(filename)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is:

```
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    df.loc[i] = 0
```

To assign a value based on a condition, this would be an example:

```
df.loc[df['value to be compared'] == 'string','column_name'] = 1
```

Comment: the first snippet didnt work but other answer fixed the first problem. The second snippet you provided, I wanted to compare a string value with the column name above it.

Comment: yeah, then put the column name above it as `'string'`